# Is it possible to pass HTML input field variables to a custom Angularjs filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, filter

I'm new to Angular so this might be real easy. 
I have a JSON array of some offers. Each offer has a price among other things. I want to be able to add a filter so that the user can specify their min/max spent and only sees offers that fall into these brackets.

In the list controller I have

```
// MinMax filter:
        $scope.minMax = function(prop, mn, mx){
            return function(item){
              if (  (Number(item[prop]) >= mn) && (Number(item[prop])<= mx) ) return true;
            }
        }
```

In the View HTML I have two simple text input fields:

```
 <input id='cheapest'   name="cheapest" type='text' value='10' />
 <input id='dearest'    name="dearest"  type='text' value='5000'  />
```

and the repeater

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in offers | filter: minMax('Price' ,  [?cheapest?], [?dearest?])  ">
```

The filter works when I hardcode values in, but how do I bind them to the input field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a calling to Captain `ngModel` ;)

Just bind your `input` values:

```
<input id='cheapest'   name="cheapest" type='text' value='10' ng-model="cheapest" />
<input id='dearest'    name="dearest"  type='text' value='5000' ng-model="dearest"  />
```

and pass the value to your filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in offers | filter: minMax('Price', cheapest, dearest)  ">
```

or access them via `$scope.cheapest` in your *controller*.

I am not sure with the syntax though but it will work somehow :)